# I am facing this issue in reactjs "Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined" and this is related to bootstrap. check below screenshot

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, react-bootstrap

This issue shows on website loading and sometime stuck on same like screenshot:

[image]

Please let me know if there is any solution for this.

Comment: What is the error on chrome developer console?

Comment: at first sight, looks like jquery isnt loaded yet, try putting an load eventlistener around the function so it will execute after jquery is loaded, or load the script file after jquery is loaded